# Bower throwing exception when run with --config.interactive=false

Tags: bower

If I use `bower install` I get the following error....

```
bower                          EINVEND The key must be specified
```

Any ideas? Windows 7 with newest stable node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops my bad, in my

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "*",
    "": "" << Here is the issue
  },
  ...
}
```

But that error message was not very good.